# Using Octave instead of Matlab in control engineering

Tags: control, matlab

I would like to know if in a first course in control systems at the undergraduate level I would miss much by using Octave instead of Matlab? I understand that Matlab has simulink but regarding basic control system design, is Octave enough?

Comment: check the toolboxes for functionality by comparing functions., both of them are available online.

Comment: For undergraduate Control, Octave is fine. Command set is identical to Matlab, but toolboxes are limited - the Control Systems toolbox is provided in the latest versions though. Matlab does have a student version that is low cost and includes Simulink.

Comment: @Chu I would preferably go for an older book in Control since newer books seem to use Simulink. Yes toolboxes are somewhat limited in Octave and everything is not as polished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finished my masters degree in electrical engineering one month ago and throughout my entire studies, i only used octave instead of matlab. I also had some control systems classes, which can be perfectly done with the `control` toolbox for octave (it is not built in). However, as you mentioned, octave has nothing like simulink, so if you need something like that, you don't really have a choice. For the matlab part and the usual undergraduate control systems classes, octave should be perfectly fine!

Comment: Is "octave" a product name? "Octave"?

Comment: @Transistor It is.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: Have you heard of, or used, OpenModelica? I've only just started trying it out, but it seems as though it may be useful here. I have to admit no familiarity with simulink except for a quick google search and a minute's reading time, though. But perhaps your background would allow you to quickly see about it. And good answer!

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time hearing of OpenModelica, so thank you alot for pointing this out. I will definately have a look into this.

Comment: @pschulz Glad to point it out. I only heard about it a few months back and found it an interesting tool which provided a service and convenience that I didn't have in other tools. I'm still learning about it as time allows. But it's one of those tools that I perceive I will be still more glad of, as I learn better how to apply it. (You need to write "@jonk" in your message if you want this software to ping me with a notice that you wrote back -- just FYI.)

Comment: @pschulz Your feedback is indeed very useful. I am already using the signal processing toolbox in Octave and it's fine for now. I should avoid newer textbooks that use Simulink.

Comment: @jonk Books on Modelica are unfortunately not that cheap. But Modelica has gained much popularity at Swedish Universities. It is also quite used in industry.

Comment: @user11206 I didn't buy a book on Modelica, yet. Just been going through web tutorials and applying my own experiences from elsewhere, so far. But thanks for the clue about their cost. I'll probably hold short of buying expensive books on the topic.